# Combinar %02d y %.2f en Python

Tags: python

En un programa hecho en Python quiero que me imprima la variable s como un número con dos cifras enteras y dos decimales (01.00 por ejemplo) usando los comandos `%.2f` y `%02d`. Con las variables h i m, que son siempre números enteros, ya he sido capaz de hacer que se expresen siempre con dos dígitos (07 por ejemplo), pero no se como combinar los dos comandos con la variable s.
Adjunto el código en cuestión:
`print("%02d" %h, "%02d" %m, "%.2f" %s, sep=":")`

Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Solución: `05.2f`

Para el caso de punto flotante, la primera cantidad (`05`) nos dice el espacio total disponible es el resultado y el cero ordena rellenar con ceros por la izquierda.

En este caso, `05` nos da cinco posiciones:

1. Dos para la parte entera.
2. Una para el punto decimal.
3. Dos para la fracción.

*Demo*

```
v=2.34
print(f"{v:05.2f}") # ->  02.34
```

Comment: Como no me di cuenta de eso? No uso mucho ese aspecto del formateo de cadenas. En fin, dejare mi respuesta como alternativa

Comment: @DanteS. A todos nos pasa.

Answer (score 0):

No parece existir una forma de combinar ambas especificaciones de formato de forma nativa. Sin embargo, podés lograr algo parecido con ayuda del modulo string, el cual posee una clase Formatter, donde podemos crear nuestros propios parsers. A continuación, te dejo un ejemplo simple:

###### Código

```
import string
import re

class Formatter(string.Formatter):
    padded_float = re.compile(r"(?P<ints>\d+)i\.(?P<dec>\d+)f")

    def format_field(self, value, format_spec):
        m = self.padded_float.fullmatch(format_spec)
        
        if(m is None):
            return super().format_field(value, format_spec)
        else:
            ints = int(m["ints"])
            dec = int(m["dec"])
            
            return ("{:.%sf}" % dec).format(value).zfill(ints + dec + 1)
            

f = Formatter()
print(f.format("{:3i.2f}", 1))
```

###### Produce

```
001.00
```

#### Explicación

Con un regex, que explicaré mas abajo, tratamos de adivinar si la cadena tiene el formato `[numero de enteros]i.[numero de decimales]f`. Si lo tiene, obtenemos ambos números, usamos una forma nativa para formatear los decimales del número y rellenamos la cadena de ceros con zfill hasta que alcance el largo `cantidad de enteros + cantidad de decimales + 1`. El 1 es por el punto que queda en medio.

#### Explicación de la regex

La regex es una forma excelente de analizar cadenas complejas que, como dice su nombre, son regulares. La interpretación de esta regex sería:

- `(?P<ints>\d+)`, `(?P<dec>\d+)` uno o más caracteres numericos (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 o 9), guardados en el grupo ints y dec respectivamente.
- `i`,  `f`. Son eso mismo, esos mismos caracteres. Es importante que estén en minusculas.
- `\.` es el regex ., pero escapado. El . sin escapar significa "cualquier caracter". Pero como buscamos al . en si, lo escapamos.